# Escaping output in tcsh completion by program

Tags: autocomplete, tcsh

How do I escape output in the program providing completion? Suppose:

```
tcsh% complete foo 'p/*/`mycomp`/'
```

And mycomp is a Perl program printing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "one\n";
print "two three\n";
print "four\\ five\n";
print "six\\\\ seven\n";
```

Then when I do:

```
tcsh% foo <tab>
```

tcsh still won't give me "two three" or the other two-word entries as single entries, but prints this:

```
five  four\ one   seven six\\ three two
```

Where each word (+ backslashes) is a single entry.

Comment: AFAIK I know, this is not possible. But I didn't dig that deep in the source, so I *might* be wrong.